# Where on a remote workstation should I put a CSV-config file for distributed JMeter testing?

Tags: java, testing, configuration, jmeter

I want to make JMeter distributed testing. It was said in the manual that first I should start `jmeter-server` on remote nodes, and then I should update `jmeter.config` and run `jmeter` on a master node.

I did all these steps. My test plan includes working with CSV-config files. If I test just from 1 (master) node - then everything works as a charm. But when I try distributed testing all tests fail. Some investigation showed that remote nodes send requests without substitution of `${..}`-like parameters. Requests look like

> POST data:
>   5|0|6|http://host.com/portal/|67D1C612DCF291DCD0F71AD15E404F37|host.ui.client.services.LoginService|login|java.lang.String/2004016611|${ADMIN_LOGIN}|1|2|3|4|3|5|5|5|6|6|1|

It's obvious that remote `jmeter-server` cannot find the CSV-file. Where should I put it?

P.S: I have machines with different OS (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04).

Comment: Did you find a workable solution?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to resolve the multiple OS issue is to put the CSV file in the Jmeter BIN directory on all test machines, and do not reference the path in the CSV Data Set Config component.

Answer (score 2):

Put a full path and filename into your 'CSV Data Set Config' component, eg. `c:\loadtest\config.csv` and ensure that you put the CSV file in the place that is specified.

---

The components [manual](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) also states the following:

> Relative file names are resolved with respect to the path of the active test plan.

So it should be possible to put the file in the same directory as the test plan file. This ought to work in both Linux and Windows.

Comment: And what about Ubuntu? Is it possible to make testing on machines with different OSs at the same time?

Comment: You know, I've just tried to set absolute path as you adviced and yes, it works. But there's a problem with Linux/Windows differences.

Comment: I've added an extra bit about relative paths.

Comment: Wait, I don't get it. As I understand from this manual, it's not even necessary to put test plan anywhere on remote nodes because it'll be sent over the net from the master node anyway.

Comment: Hmm, you could try adding two 'CSV Data Set Config' components, the first with the Windows style path and the second with the Linux based path.

Answer (score 1):

Any reference to data file assumes that such a file exists in respective nodes in the specified path.  For example, if you have your CSV files in C:\data, then when you execute the test plan in a distributed fashion, the testplan would look for the data file in C:\data of the node (the slave).

In effect, if you are using 10 slave machines, you need to have c:\data folder in all those 10 machines.

There is no need to copy test plan.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED** because the docs reference was wrong - I got burned by my own answer :)

Old question, but I just ran into this issue and the answers here are conflicting.

Is a relative path resolved to the bin/ directory, or to the directory of the current .jmx test script?

Answer: it is only the directory of the test script. From the docs:

> **Relative file names are resolved with
>   respect to the path of the active test plan.** Absolute file names are
>   also supported, but note that they are unlikely to work in remote
>   mode, unless the remote server has the same directory structure. If
>   the same physical file is referenced in two different ways - e.g.
>   csvdata.txt and ./csvdata.txt - then these are treated as different
>   files. If the OS does not distinguish between upper and lower case,
>   csvData.TXT would also be opened separately.

Comment: 5 years later and I'm trying to get this up and running in Kubernetes and this was useful!