# Jmeter remote run and CSV files

Tags: linux, jmeter

I have JMeter (2.8) tests which are working perfectly when run locally and fail when run remotely.
The only difference how I run those is `-r` switch (or `-R <list of machines>`), all other parameters are exactly same.

Test are failing in remote mode since variables which should contain values from CSV file contain `<EOF>` value - this means that test failed to load CSV file.

I've uploaded CSV files to `bin` directory of JMeter on each remote machine ([as someone suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3998522/1387438)), but this doesn't help.

I'm using Linux machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Jmeter documentation:

```
Relative file names are resolved with respect to the path of the active test plan.
For distributed testing, the CSV file must be stored on the server host system in the 
correct relative directory to where the jmeter server is started.</b>
Absolute file names are also supported, but note that they are unlikely to work in remote 
mode, unless the remote server has the same directory structure.
```

Another option is to use a variable as base folder for CSV files and to set it at startup on each remote server:

```
-Jresdir=<CSV Folder>
```

Comment: I've missed that in documentation. Starting jmeter servers from proper directory fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that jmeter-server is looking for some thing on the path "jmeter/file-from-ui.csv". Found this by using strace.

I solved my issue by adding a jmeter folder in the dir that i started jmeter-server in and putting my csv files in there.